# Powershell - Failing to return as objects to variables

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I have a powershell script that I am trying to use to destroy a subscriptions resource groups based on the environment.

However I seem to get the following error everytime I try to get the resource names into a variable as objects.

```
# Set the variables here
$_subscription = "Test Data Platform"
$_environment = "prd" #prd, dev, uat

Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $_subscription

Write-Host ("The acquired list of resource group names is as below:")
$rgs=Get-AzResourceGroup -Tag @{'environment'=$_environment} | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName

$rgs | ForEach-Object -Parallel  {
    $r = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $_ -Tag @{'environment'=$_environment} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($r) {
        $message = "We have a resource group called {0}" -f $_
        Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Output
        try {
            $message = "###   Removing resource group {0}" -f $_
            Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Output
            Remove-AzResourceGroup -Name $_ -Confirm:$false -Force | Out-Null
            $message = "###   Resource group {0} Removed" -f $_
            Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Output
        }
        catch {
            $message = "###   FAILED - REMOVING -Resource group {0}" -f $_
            Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Significant
        }
    }
    else {
        $message = "There is no resource group called {0}" -f $_
        Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Output
    }
} -ThrottleLimit 25
```

Error

```
ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Test\destroy-dev-az.ps1:10 char:8
+ $rgs | ForEach-Object -Parallel  {
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Run it in Powershell 7 instead and got the following error:

```
The acquired list of resource group names is as below:
[15:44:46][<ScriptBlock>] There is no resource group called @{ResourceGroupName=Test2}
[15:44:47][<ScriptBlock>] There is no resource group called @{ResourceGroupName=Test1}
```

**UPDATE**

Resolved the above error by changing `$rgs` to `$rgs.ResourceGroupName`.

Comment: The error message suggests your PowerShell version version is below 7. Note that `-Parallel` was implemented on __PowerShell 7.0 Preview 3__.

Comment: What PowerShell version are you running?

Comment: How is the script deployed? Azure Pipelines? Function App? Running off a VM?

Comment: Ah i was running this in Powershell ISE and I think that is version 5. I've got windows Terminal that runs it in 7 I shall try running the script in PS 7.

Comment: @Lynchie that will probably solve the issue. In case you need to run this on Windows PowerShell (v5.1) you would need to resort to Runspace or use the ThreadJob module from MS.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Please see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Santiago Squarzon** has mentioned `ForEach-Object -Parallel` was introduced in ***PowerShell 7.0 Preview 3*** , so If you are using ***Powershell ISE*** it will be of `Version 5.0`. So , You will get error as below :

[image]

If you run in ***Powershell 7*** , then the issue is that the command you are using to ***get resource group names*** by using `select-object` returns output with a ***CRLF endings*** and using that as a parameter in another command will give you below errors:

```
ERROR: Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$'.
```

##### OR

[image]

***So , inorder to solve that you will need to get the resource names with this command `$rgs=(Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName`. so your over all code will be like below :***

```
# Set the variables here
$_subscription = "Test Data Platform"
$_environment = "prd" #prd, dev, uat

Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $_subscription

Write-Host ("The acquired list of resource group names is as below:")
$rgs=(Get-AzResourceGroup -Tag @{'environment'=$_environment}).ResourceGroupName

$rgs | ForEach-Object -Parallel  {
    $r = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $_ -Tag @{'environment'=$_environment} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($r) {
        $message = "We have a resource group called {0}" -f $_
        Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Output
        try {
            $message = "###   Removing resource group {0}" -f $_
            Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Output
            Remove-AzResourceGroup -Name $_ -Confirm:$false -Force | Out-Null
            $message = "###   Resource group {0} Removed" -f $_
            Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Output
        }
        catch {
            $message = "###   FAILED - REMOVING -Resource group {0}" -f $_
            Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Significant
        }
    }
    else {
        $message = "There is no resource group called {0}" -f $_
        Write-PSFMessage $message -Level Output
    }
} -ThrottleLimit 25
```

**Output:**

[image]